# laravel validation, Rule::exists or Rule::in

Tags: php, laravel, validation, rules

I want to validate sequence of items. In my idea sequence field must be exists in database sequence column or must be one plus more than maximum of present sequence.
I have this code in view:

```
<select id="sequence" name="sequence" value="{{ old('sequence') }}">
  @foreach ($items = App\Models\Item::all()->sortBy('sequence') as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->sequence }}">{{ $item->sequence }}</option>
  @endforeach
    <option value="{{ $items->max('sequence') + 1 }}">{{ $items->max('sequence') + 1 }}</option>
</select>
```

now I have a problem to validate request('sequence') in controller.
I'm looking for some code like this

```
Rule::exists('items', 'sequence') OR equal => ($items->max('sequence') + 1)
```

Note: I have a function for updating sequence when the value isn't maximum plus one.

Comment: Where did you validate your request data, `Controller` or `FormRequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Rule::when()` to validate.

```
use App\Models\Item;

$max = Item::max('sequence');
```

**Controller**

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'sequence' => ['required', 'integer', Rule::when($request->sequence != $max + 1, ['exists:items,sequence'])],
]);
```

Or,

**FormRequest**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'sequence' => ['required', 'integer', Rule::when($this->sequence != $max + 1, ['exists:items,sequence'])],
    ]; 
}
```

Comment: I valid my data in Controller.
It doesn't work and I didn't find anything in Laravel docs about Rule::when. I think I should use costum validation

Comment: In docs it is not mention, but if you go to Rule class you will find there.